# Extending ObjectCache to create a file-based cache alternative

Tags: asp.net, caching, c#-4.0, file-io

We are working on an ASP.Net MVC/Jquery mobile project for a chain of Australian holiday parks. The bulk of park related data is stored in a SQL database.

One of the sections currently in development is 'local attractions'. The data for this section is pulled from a webservice owned by the Australian Tourism Data Warehouse (ATDW). Though it can take up to 45 seconds for the view to load, fortunately for us the data is reasonably static. We are planning to cache it, and refresh it on a weekly basis. This data is also relatively large. I consider that it is not a suitable candidate for in-memory caching.

I am interested in a file based implementation of the System.Runtime.ObjectCache.

I have scoured the internet and I haven't managed to find any examples of this. My question is general, and I am looking for advice on reading/writing to a file based cache. The data will be retrieved by the class CachedLocalAttractionsService.cs in a services tier which is called directly from the controller.

Please advise on:
Storing name/value pairs on disk,
Serializing large amounts of data retrievable in a Cache[key] fashion,
Any examples that I might have missed in my 6 hours of searching so far.

Comment: Though I was keen to create a custom implementation of the ObjectCache, I ended up going down a different road. 
Rather than having a dependancy on the FileCache, I moved most of the storage logic into the service and forewent the advantages that ObjectCache entailed ie invalidation policy.

I have used a protocol buffer dll for the serialization to hard disk, and the cache key was rolled in to the filename, and rather than check the cache, ie if cache[key] != null, checked the disk instead ie if ((str = FileCache.Read(key)) != null)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option for file system cache/search is probably to use a Lucene index.

However if your content is quite static then could you not perhaps look into using Output caching?

Trivial example

```
[OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will cache this return for 10 seconds.

Check here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
What we see as the deficiency with output caching is that sporadically a user will have to endure the delay while the data is pulled and the output cache is refreshed.
We were looking to cache the information to the file system, set the expiry, and then create a behind the scenes process to load this cache on a weekly basis by creating a web service entry point and to consume it out of hours to refresh the cache